# console2 colors solarized

Tags: windows, console, console2

I am trying to use Solarized colors on a Windows 7 pc using Console2. I can't get the colors to work correctly though.

I tried changing the entries in console.xml as suggested [here](https://github.com/stevenharman/console2-solarized). Is this all I need to do?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Copied from the instructions [here](http://www.curlybrace.com/words/2012/02/12/console2-and-cygwin-with-solarized-color-palette/):

> Replace the `<colors> ... </colors>` section with the following:
>
> `<colors>
>      <color id="0" r="7" g="54" b="66"/>         <!-- black -->
>      <color id="1" r="38" g="139" b="210"/>      <!-- blue -->
>      <color id="2" r="133" g="153" b="0"/>       <!-- green -->
>      <color id="3" r="42" g="161" b="152"/>      <!-- cyan -->
>      <color id="4" r="220" g="50" b="47"/>       <!-- red -->
>      <color id="5" r="211" g="54" b="130"/>      <!-- magenta -->
>      <color id="6" r="181" g="137" b="0"/>       <!-- yellow/brown -->
>      <color id="7" r="238" g="232" b="213"/>     <!-- white -->
>      <color id="8" r="0" g="43" b="54"/>         <!-- brblack -->
>      <color id="9" r="131" g="148" b="150"/>     <!-- brblue -->
>      <color id="10" r="88" g="110" b="117"/>     <!-- brgreen -->
>      <color id="11" r="147" g="161" b="161"/>    <!-- brcyan -->
>      <color id="12" r="203" g="75" b="22"/>      <!-- brred -->
>      <color id="13" r="108" g="113" b="196"/>    <!-- brmagenta/violet -->
>      <color id="14" r="101" g="123" b="131"/>    <!-- bryellow -->
>      <color id="15" r="253" g="246" b="227"/>    <!-- brwhite  -->
>   </colors>`

This worked beautifully for me.

Comment: At first it didn't work for me because I edited the console.xml file in the program folder. Editing the `c:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Console\console.xml` file did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I've gone through the same process and the color scheme seem to work for me.  One thing to check would be to open up the Console2 settings dialog and verify that your *Console Colors Map* are properly mapped.  The attached screen shot is using the dark solarize color scheme.

[image: Console Settings with Solarized Console Color Map]