# Emacs on Windows 7: How to get color theme »solarized-light« working?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I'm using Emacs 24 on Windows 7. I installed the solarized theme, see here: https://github.com/sellout/emacs-color-theme-solarized

It is easy to switch to the color-theme, e.g. by doing M-x load-theme and then pick solarized-light.

But especially the colors of solarized-light are nearly unreadable. The colors are not even close to the colors of the pictures. I guess there is something wrong with a thing called »color palette«, see here: [console2 colors solarized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12779826/console2-colors-solarized)

Any ideas?

---

Edit: I made a screenshot of Emacs which shows the pretty low contrast.

[image: Solarized-light-theme on Emacs under Windows 7]

Comment: Are you also using Emacs in console?

Comment: No, just the usual Windows-exe offered by GNU.org

Comment: I guess not (so the console colors palette is not a fault here). Although the same .exe can be launched in a console when called with `-nw` argument.

Answer (score 2):

So, I installed it now, and I see the lack of contrast. But the difference seems to be cause by the difference in font rendering across operating systems.

The screenshots on the github page have most likely been done on Mac OS, which renders the fonts the thickest. The theme looks reasonable on Linux with the default font, although, depending on the settings, it renders the text a bit or more thinner. And Windows renders text with the smallest amount of "ink", so to speak. While it's considered sharper my some users, it also makes things worse when a theme uses low-contrast colors, such as the light version of Solarized.

Another thing to note is that the screenshots are done in Vim, which has a different syntax highlighting mechanism from Emacs, so the colors on keywords, etc, are bound to be different.

But I took two screenshots, on Ubuntu and Windows, opened them in Gimp, zoomed in, used the color picker, and the value of the blue color was approximately the same as on the reference screenshot: `2690db`.

Comment: I added a screenshot, just to make sure that you make the same experience. Used your text . . .

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Maybe slightly better due to the different font size and family (11.5 pt Consolas): http://i.imgur.com/lzxLf.png

Comment: Any idea how to improve it? It's way better on Linux, but I'd like it on Windows as well.

Comment: Experiment with different fonts, maybe. But personally I haven't seen any font that I like better on Windows than Consolas.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, i don't feel the theme work improperly.
The following is my screenshot, os x, Emacs 24.3

Have you tried to change another font or theme (if that is not your only love)

[image: the emacs theme: solar-light screen shot]

Comment: OK, then the solarized-theme simply is not friendly to my eyes.

Comment: I prefer some dark-based themes.  Now I'm using the theme from https://github.com/owainlewis/emacs-color-themes. You can try and feel.